# Reallocating array size using type of its element

Tags: java, arrays, allocation

I have a class attribute which is an `Anytype` built-in array. At some point I need to reallocate it’s memory to double it, but since it is `Anytype`, I **can’t do**:

```
myArray = new Anytype[myArray.length * 2];
```

Since the array is already defined, I can access to it’s elements class:

```
myArray[0].getClass();
```

**My question is:** Can I use the fact that I know the class of my array to reallocate it? I know I could use `Arrays.copyOf` from Java utils, but I want to know if it is possible to reallocate knowing the size your object need, *kind of a C-way*:

```
myArray = new myArray[0].getAllocationNeeded()[myArray.length * 2];
```

P.S: *I’m not sure if the title is relevant, please indicate me if you have something more clear*

Comment: You want a dynamic length array? look at ArrayList

Comment: "I can’t do: `myArray = new Anytype[myArray.length * 2]`" => Why? This is exactly how it is done. What does the elements type have to do with the size of the array?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, probably, he doesn't want to lose data which keeps there

Comment: @Gordon can’t do sir, I know it’s the right way however i **need to implement it with built-in array**.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Then the reference to the _new_ array must be assigned to another variable, then you can copy the content. This question is unclear!

Comment: @UlysseBN you can create a property like thing to update the "built-in array"

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well the compiler throwed us an error for it, unfortunately I don’t have the code with me... I’ll upload it as soon as possible. So you mean `Anytype` guess the needed size?
Anyway this is not about keeping my array’s data (I’m already making a copy of it)

Comment: @UlysseBN You seem to think that the type (here: `AnyType`) has any influence on the size of an array. **It does not!** And if you already tried something out and failed, you have to put it into your question.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Ok my bad, my error must come from somewhere else... I’ll come back with an MCVE

Comment: @Gordon I don’t get what you’re saying..

Comment: You may be still thinking in C.  In Java the size of the array type has no bearing on the size of the array, because the array contains only _references_ to the array elements.  You never multiply the number elements by the size of an element, the way you would do in C.

Comment: I can update my question, i _finally_ have the code back! Though I think I’ll create a new one, since it is different than this one (not for copy but initialization of an `AnyType` array in a class with this kind of signature: `class ArrayQueue<AnyType>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, something like this (assume source is not null or empty):

```
   public <T> T[] resizeArray(T[] source, int multiplier) {
    T[] newArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(source.getClass().getComponentType(), source.length * multiplier);
    System.arraycopy(source, 0, newArray, 0, source.length);
    return newArray;
}
```

Both:

- source.getClass().getComponentType()
- myArray[0].getClass()

Return the element class.

Comment: Thanks, according to comments that may not be what I’m looking for, but it’s definitely what I thought I would get. I hope your downvoter will explain himself, so we know the issue if there is.

Comment: Ok now that I solved my problem, I can accept your answer : I used it. And I also used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924453/6320039) for the array initialization.